# How to specify max length for a computed column

Tags: sql-server

I am adding a computed column from three fields. It will be a VARCHAR field. I need to specify the max length for the computed column. How can we specify that.

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD  CustomNumber AS [PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ]
```

Is there a way I can restrict it? I need to raise an error if it is more than 10 character long

Reference: [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)

Comment: The max length will be calculated automatically from the component parts. Why do you want to specify a max length explicitly and what should happen if the length exceeds that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
[PGM] VARCHAR(50),
[GRP] VARCHAR(50),
[PGMGRPSEQ] VARCHAR(50),
CustomNumber AS [PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ] PERSISTED CHECK (LEN(CustomNumber) <= 10)
)
```

Or if you don't want to persist the computed column just add a check constraint that repeats the expression.

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
[PGM] VARCHAR(50),
[GRP] VARCHAR(50),
[PGMGRPSEQ] VARCHAR(50),
CustomNumber AS [PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ],
CHECK (LEN([PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ] ) <= 10)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, say, max length is 100, then:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD  CustomNumber 
    AS Ltrim(Substring([PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ]  + Space(100), 1, 100))
```

Comment: This doesn't do what is asked.

Comment: Good point, @MartinSmith. Sorry i missed the error raising part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
[PGM] VARCHAR(50),
[GRP] VARCHAR(50),
[PGMGRPSEQ] VARCHAR(50)
)

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD  CustomNumber AS [PGM]+'-'+[GRP]+'-'+[PGMGRPSEQ] PERSISTED
GO
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
ADD CONSTRAINT [MaxLenLimit] CHECK (LEN([CustomNumber]) <= 100)
```

Comment: "Computed Column 'CustomNumber' in table 'MyTable' is invalid for use in 'CHECK CONSTRAINT' because it is not persisted."